# Highlight a feature in ArcMap from a web page

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, c#, powershell

I have a web page that calls a PowerShell script to switch to ArcMap. I only want one instance of ArcMap running. If I open a new instance of ArcMap I can easily pass the PlotId as an Argument. However if the application is already running how do I display the PlotId in ArcMap. I have developed a ArcObject listener to display a feature in a layer. Is there a way of passing the PlotId to ArcMap to display the plot when its already running?

```
param([Int32]$plotId=0) 

#requires -Version 2
function Show-Process($Process, [Switch]$Maximize)
{
  $sig = '
    [DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hwnd);
  '
  
  if ($Maximize) { $Mode = 3 } else { $Mode = 4 }
  $type = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $sig -Name WindowAPI -PassThru
  $hwnd = $process.MainWindowHandle
  $null = $type::ShowWindowAsync($hwnd, $Mode)
  $null = $type::SetForegroundWindow($hwnd) 
}

$arcmap = Get-Process -Name 'Arcmap' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($arcmap){
    Show-Process($arcmap, [Switch]$Maximize)
} else {
    $arcmapPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.6\bin\ArcMap.exe"
    Start-Process -FilePath $arcmapPath $plotId
}
```

Base on this powershell tip
https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/bringing-window-in-the-foreground

Comment: There are ways to send information to another application, but all would involve writing some custom code (for instance an ArcMap addin) to handle the incoming information. By itself, ArcMap wouldn't know what to do with an 'ID field', whatever you mean by that.

Comment: Thanks. The PlotId is a property of a feature in the map. I was looking at .net Remoting and WCF but I think this is overkill. Is there a simpler was of doing it, e.g. can a Python script interact with the ArcMap UI from outside of the application?

Comment: Not that I know. If you want a simple solution, you could store the value in a file, and then write a simple arcmap addin that uses a `FileSystemWatcher` object to respond to changes in that file.

Comment: It's a long time since I have written this sort of code but I had developed code in MS Access that would control Arcmap through automation, search for that term. I remember approt being a key object to grab a running instance of Arcmap.